How to measure Lithium-ion battery SoC?
I have a 48 V 12 Ah Lithium-ion battery pack.
I am struggling in finding a way to measure its State of Charge.
It will be charged through a 13S JBD BMS.
I need to spit out information from the battery to show it to the user via the MCU. The BMS won't show it to the user.
How can I get the real State of Charge of this Battery pack?
Note: I know that there are these fuel gauge IC. However, most of them are for single cell, not for 48 V nominal batteries. There are some of analog devices ICs designed for 48 V, however it is expensive for this design so it should be a tight budget one.

Do not conflate capacity and State of Charge. Even though they both use Ah as units, they are different parameters. While discharging, capacity remains the same while State of Charge decreases. I believe you're asking about measuring the State of Charge, not the Capacity.

@DavideAndrea didn't know they are different, thanks for the note Sir.

You should check the market offerings more carefully. For example, TI offers a line-up of high-voltage monitoring IC, with 80-85V range. Here is the one, INA228,
Application diagram:

INA237 is ~$1.90 in qty 1 from TI Direct. What else can be less expensive for such a wide and integrated functionality?
Also, the battery State of Charge is somewhat elusive parameter. The monitoring IC only allows you to capture the battery's charge-discharge curves and monitor the charge ins and outs. You will need to get the discharge curve by running several full charge - full discharge cycles while measuring the instant voltage and current, say, every second (or every minute, depending on your load). Then you will need to calculate an integral of your data (which gives you the true battery capacity), and only then you can assign approximate value of SoC for the discharge voltage curve. Still the actual SoC will depend on the particular discharge current as the capacity varies with discharge rates.

do you know where can I find more models(not only for TI)?
